# How to look up a string in a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I've got a file that contains a list of 3-letter strings (codons for those who know biology) in a column. In my program, I have constructed a dictionary, where each particular string corresponds to a designated letter (amino acids for those who know biology). So, I want my program to go through this entire list of strings/codons and for each codon, I want the program to look it up on the dictionary and output which letter that given codon/string corresponds to. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience using dictionaries, so I'm not sure how to look it up. I've tried something but I keep getting errors. The variable 'new_codon' contains the list of strings/amino acids from the file that I'm using. Here's what I've got so far:

```
codon_lookup = {'GCT': 'A', 'GCC': 'A','GCA': 'A','GCG': 'A', 'TGT':'C','TGC':'C',    'GAT':'D','GAC': 'D', 'GAA':'E','GAG': 'E', 'TTT':'F','TTC': 'F', 'GGT': 'G','GGC': 'G','GGA':'G','GGG': 'G', 'CAT':'H','CAC': 'H', 'ATT':'I','ATC':'I','ATA':'I','AAA':'K','AAG':'K', 'TTA': 'L','TTG': 'L','CTT': 'L','CTC': 'L','CTA': 'L','CTG': 'L', 'ATG': 'M', 'AAT':'N','AAC':'N', 'CCT': 'P','CCC': 'P','CCA': 'P','CCG': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q','CAG': 'Q', 'CGT': 'R','CGC': 'R','CGA': 'R','CGG': 'R','AGA': 'R','AGG': 'R', 'TCT': 'S','TCC': 'S','TCA': 'S','TCG': 'S','AGT': 'S','AGC': 'S', 'ACT': 'T','ACC': 'T','ACA': 'T','ACG': 'T', 'GTT': 'V','GTC': 'V','GTA': 'V','GTG': 'V', 'TGG':'W', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAC':'Y', 'TAA': 'Z', 'TAG': 'Z', 'TGA':'Z'}

for x in new_codon:
   codon_lookup[x]
   if codon_lookup[x] == ref_aa[x]: # Here I'm comparing it to another list I have from another file to see if they match or don't match 
             print "1"
   else: 
           print "0"
```

Comment: Please describe your exact problem... currently it's hard to tell where you think you are wrong... what output do you expect, what do you get? Try to not just put out 0 or 1, but some more "helpful" values

Comment: Can you specify the _errors_?

Comment: @Vogel612 That is the output that I'm trying to get.

Comment: @SimeonVisser  Just edited my program to reflect your question.

Comment: @SweeneyTodd I get KeyError: 'ATC\r\n'. I have no idea what this means but ATC is the first string in my file, so I guess for some reason it's not being read properly?

Comment: The `\r\n` is a Windows-style newline sequence - Python includes them when you read lines from a file. `strip` or `rstrip` are the usual tools to remove them.

Comment: And the obligatory biopython plug: the `translate` function looks up amino acids by codons. http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Seq-module.html#translate

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks for letting me know. I just fixed it, but now there's a new problem. For some reason the program won't compare my two lists where I have used the if statement. Check out my response to gnibbler's suggestion below.

Comment: @bioprogrammer - we need to see what `ref_aa` looks like. From the error you're describing, it's a list, and of course you can't index into a list with a string. But I can't tell you how to do what you're trying to do without seeing it.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I didn't code the ref_aa list. I appended it from a file that contains the list in the exact same format as my new_codon list.

Comment: @bioprogrammer - we still need to see the source for it. The error you are reporting means it is not a dictionary.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper It's not a dictionary. It's a txt file. However, I appended it into a list earlier in the code (not posted here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `KeyError` if the element you asked is NOT in the dictionary.
And you are asking for `"ATC\r\n"` instead of `"ATC"`. The problem is not in this part of the code. You are just reading the `new_codon` with endline characters.
All you have to do is add a simple statement to remove endline characters from the end of your string `x`.

```
codon_lookup = {'GCT': 'A', 'GCC': 'A',...}

for x in new_codon:
   #This statement(`codon_lookup[x]`) was pointless
   x = x[:3] # Removes the part after the third character
   if codon_lookup[x] == ref_aa[x]: # Here I'm comparing it to another list I have from another file to see if they match or don't match 
           print "1"
   else: 
           print "0"
```

If `ref_aa` is a list, you will get `TypeError` of course.
`x` is a string, `ref_aa` is a list; you cannot use `ref_aa[x]`. To fix this issue, you can use `enumerate`([docs for enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)):

```
codon_lookup = {'GCT': 'A', 'GCC': 'A',...}

for i,x in enumerate(new_codon):
   x = x[:3] # Removes the part after the third character
   if codon_lookup[x] == ref_aa[i]: # Changed the 'x' with 'i' for list 
           print "1"
   else: 
           print "0"
```

Comment: This works. There seems to be a problem with the line where I am comparing the two lists using the if statement. The error I get is: TypeError: list indices must be integers not str. I don't get why the program can't compare two strings...I've had no issues in the past.

Comment: So how would I go about doing the comparison then?

Comment: I cannot tell it unless you explain what `ref_aa` consists of.

Comment: ref_aa consists of a list of amino acids (is this what you wanted to know?). I want to compare whether the amino acid that corresponds to new_codon is the same as the amino acids that are contained in ref_aa.

Comment: There is no `'I'` as a key in your dictionary, it is a value. Thus if you try `codon_lookup['I']` it will give KeyError. It is really hard to figure out the solution without seeing the content of `new_codon` and `ref_aa`.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your `KeyError`

```
for x in new_codon:
    x = x.rstrip() # remove line seperators
    ...
```

For your question in the comments.

```
for x, aa in zip(new_codon, ref_aa):
    x = x.rstrip() # remove line seperators

    if codon_lookup[x] == aa: 
        print "1"
    else: 
        print "0"
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. So what was the initial problem? Also, now that this line works, there seems to be a problem with the line where I am comparing the two lists using the if statement. The error I get is: TypeError: list indices must be integers not str. I don't get why the program can't compare two strings...I've had no issues in the past.

Comment: Keep in mind that lists and dictionaries are different things. `codon_lookup` is not a list at all. That might help you more clearly explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I understand. The problem appears to be that I'm comparing a dictionary to a list, but what can I do differently to be able to compare the two?

Comment: @bioprogrammer - it depends entirely on what's in `ref_aa`. Which is why I am so insistent that you show us what it contains.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper ref_aa consists of a list of amino acids (is this what you wanted to know?). I want to compare whether the amino acid that corresponds to new_codon is the same as the amino acids that are contained in ref_aa.

Comment: @bioprogrammer - so are you just trying to ensure that the amino acid code is present in the list? If so, use the `set` approach in gnibbler's answer.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper No. the new_codon list I have is a list of codons I have generated by random mutation. I am comparing this to ref_aa to see whether these new codons I have generated have produced synonymous or non-synonymous mutations. This is why I must compare it to ref_aa.

Comment: @bioprogrammer - so `ref_aa` is a list of the amino acids produced by the unmutated codons? OK, that's easy - `for (codon, reference_acid) in zip(new_codon, ref_aa): if codon_lookup[codon] == reference_acid:...`  Or you could use `for (index, codon) in enumerate(new_codon): if codon_lookup[codon] == ref_aa[index]:` if you like, but the `zip` method is more Pythonic IMO.

Comment: @bioprogrammer, now you seem to have worked out what you want, I've put a version using `zip` into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To check if value in a dictionary use 'is':

```
for x in new_codon:
   if x in codon_lookup:
             print "1"
   else: 
           print "0"
```